# Mathematica equivalent of `qnorm` or `invNorm`

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

In R and TI-89 you can do

`qnorm(prob, mu, sigma)` or `invNorm(prob, mu, sigma)` to get a value of `x` such that $P(Z < x)$ along a normal curve defined by the specified mean and standard deviation equals `prob`.

While I could do something like:

`Solve[CDF[NormalDistribution[mu, sigma], x] == prob, x]`

this is cumbersome.

While I could also use *Mathematica*'s RLink functionality, I would like to know whether there is a native command that does this.

Comment: You could also use [`InverseErf`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InverseErf.html), but that's cumbersome too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this is the most compact I can get without defining my own function:

`InverseCDF[NormalDistribution[mu, sigma], prob]`

Comment: `Quantile[NormalDistribution[mu, sigma], prob]` saves 2 ;-)

Comment: @ciao +1 for teaching me about a new function :D

Comment: But why not define `q[prob_, mu_, sigma_] := InverseCDF[...]`? You'd be using the native command *and* saving keystrokes.